# Emulate viewport option in the Chrome Canary device emulation panel: Weird behavior

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

I can't figure out the behavior of the "emulate viewport" option in the new Chrome's device emulation panel.

When unchecked, everything works as it should. I can visualize the device viewport in my browser and the changes I make in the code get properly visualized in the browser.

When the option is checked, though (as it is by default), it messes up my layout completely. Horizontal scrolling bars appear (even using `.container{max-width: 100%;}` or `overflow: hidden`), the font gets rendered way bigger than it should, and the browser seems to ignore my changes to the CSS.

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation?hl=it), I read:

> **Emulate viewport** - zooms the page out to the physical default viewport of that device. In the case of the Nexus 4 this is 768x1280.

Can someone please translate in plain English what kind of behavior this option activates, and why should I want to keep it flagged?

Comment: I can't answer everything but the font being bigger is related to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust there is an option in the emulation section related to enabling or disabling this portion of the emulation, I can't remember the exact wording though

Comment: Thanks for the hint -- would like to know more tho.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem. When I would simply change the resolution of the window everything would render nicely according to the screen width. But whenever I would try to emulate in Chrome with device emulator, columns would not change their size and display on the screen with their physical width. Then, I figured out to add the following line to the  section of the html file. Hope that helps.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```